# Passing a Model to Partial View when using Html.Action for Caching?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I resorted to using `@Html.Action()` to cache certain parts of the page. Because, as I understand the only way to cache views server-side is to decorate controllers' action methods with `OutputCache` attribute. Therefore I am using `@Html.Action` in the main view to render those cached partials.

The problem is that I cannot pass my view model to those partials any more. Had I been using `@Html.Partial` instead, it would not have been an issue, as I could easily pass my view model as a parameter.

So, is there a way to pass my built view model to a partial view which is to be rendered using `@Html.Action`? Or, alternatively, is there another way to cache certain partial views without resorting to child actions being invoked on a controller?

Comment: You can pass a model using `Html.Action()` (with some limitations) - is it the model in the view, of a property of the model, and what is the definition of the model you want to pass?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is a rather complex class. I could not find any suitable overload for passing it in `Html.Action`

Comment: It wont work if the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections,but if it contains just simple properties, then it will work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is a complex model unfortunately. That is why I would like to pass it as opposed to creating it again in the Controller's child action, as that would defeat the purpose of caching.